# Unable to locate package apt-get when building a custom Google Cloud Workstation image

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apt-get, google-cloud-workstations

I am trying to "build and push a modified workstations image to a container registry" as explained in this previous [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74246955/install-php-in-home-folder-of-persistent-disk-in-google-cloud-workstations).

This is the `Dockerfile` that I am trying to use:

```
FROM us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/cloud-workstations-images/predefined/code-oss:latest

RUN \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y apache2 \
  sudo apt-get install -y libbz2-dev \
  sudo apt-get install -y php && \
  sudo apt-get install php-mysqli
```

When I try to build the image using `docker build -t my-custom-image .` I eventually receive this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package apt-get
E: Unable to locate package install
E: Unable to locate package apt-get
E: Unable to locate package install
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo apt-get update &&   sudo apt-get install -y apache2   sudo apt-get install -y libbz2-dev   sudo apt-get install -y php &&   sudo apt-get install php-mysqli' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why can't I build this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the `Dockerfile` to this and now it is working:

```
FROM us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/cloud-workstations-images/predefined/code-oss:latest

RUN \
  sudo apt-get update \
  && sudo apt-get install -y apache2 \
  && sudo apt-get install -y libbz2-dev \
  && sudo apt-get install -y php \
  && sudo apt-get install php-mysqli
```